# django-oscar PriceSerializer not used but not found

Tags: django-oscar

I'm extending the CheckoutSerializer, but in the tests, when I import it to test 'validate' method, I have the next error:

```
oscar.core.exceptions.ClassNotFoundError: No class 'PriceSerializer' found in...
```

It's strange, because I'm not using PriceSerializer directly, so, why I'm having this error?

If I use the code it works perfectly.

I'm using the last version.

Update

I'm running [this](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar-api/blob/master/oscarapi/tests/unit/testcheckout.py) tests

stacktrace

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.9.7, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-1.0.0
django: settings: init.settings (from env)
rootdir: /local/app/store, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: django-4.4.0, Faker-9.7.1
collected 0 items / 1 error

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
____ ERROR collecting apps/api_extensions/tests/checkout/test_checkout_2.py ____
store/apps/api_extensions/tests/checkout/test_checkout_2.py:14: in <module>
    from store.apps.api_extensions.serializers.checkout import CheckoutSerializer
store/apps/api_extensions/serializers/checkout.py:7: in <module>
    from oscarapi.serializers import checkout as checkout_serializers
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oscarapi/serializers/checkout.py:41: in <module>
    VoucherSerializer, OfferDiscountSerializer = get_api_classes(
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oscarapi/utils/loading.py:26: in get_api_classes
    return oscarapi_class_loader(module_label, classnames, "oscarapi")
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oscarapi/utils/loading.py:16: in oscarapi_class_loader
    override_module = _import_module(override_module_name, classnames)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oscar/core/loading.py:140: in _import_module
    return __import__(module_label, fromlist=classnames)
store/apps/api_extensions/serializers/basket.py:12: in <module>
    ) = get_api_classes(
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oscarapi/utils/loading.py:26: in get_api_classes
    return oscarapi_class_loader(module_label, classnames, "oscarapi")
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oscarapi/utils/loading.py:16: in oscarapi_class_loader
    override_module = _import_module(override_module_name, classnames)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oscar/core/loading.py:140: in _import_module
    return __import__(module_label, fromlist=classnames)
store/apps/api_extensions/serializers/product.py:29: in <module>
    PriceSerializer = get_api_class("serializers.checkout", "PriceSerializer")
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oscarapi/utils/loading.py:30: in get_api_class
    return get_api_classes(module_label, [classname])[0]
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oscarapi/utils/loading.py:26: in get_api_classes
    return oscarapi_class_loader(module_label, classnames, "oscarapi")
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oscarapi/utils/loading.py:22: in oscarapi_class_loader
    return _pluck_classes(class_search_modules, classnames)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oscar/core/loading.py:175: in _pluck_classes
    raise ClassNotFoundError("No class '%s' found in %s" % (
E   oscar.core.exceptions.ClassNotFoundError: No class 'PriceSerializer' found in store.apps.api_extensions.serializers.checkout, oscarapi.serializers.checkout
=============================== warnings summary ===============================
../../usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:91
  /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:91: RemovedInDjango41Warning: 'modeltranslation' defines default_app_config = 'modeltranslation.apps.ModeltranslationConfig'. Django now detects this configuration automatically. You can remove default_app_config.
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)

../../usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:91
  /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:91: RemovedInDjango41Warning: 'haystack' defines default_app_config = 'haystack.apps.HaystackConfig'. Django now detects this configuration automatically. You can remove default_app_config.
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)

../../usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:91
  /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:91: RemovedInDjango41Warning: 'oscarapi' defines default_app_config = 'oscarapi.apps.OscarAPIConfig'. Django now detects this configuration automatically. You can remove default_app_config.
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)

../../usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oscarapi/serializers/fields.py:107
  /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oscarapi/serializers/fields.py:107: RemovedInDjango40Warning: django.utils.translation.ugettext() is deprecated in favor of django.utils.translation.gettext().
    "no_such_option": _("{code}: Option {value} does not exist."),

../../usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oscarapi/serializers/fields.py:108
  /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oscarapi/serializers/fields.py:108: RemovedInDjango40Warning: django.utils.translation.ugettext() is deprecated in favor of django.utils.translation.gettext().
    "invalid": _("Wrong type, {error}."),

../../usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oscarapi/serializers/fields.py:109
  /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oscarapi/serializers/fields.py:109: RemovedInDjango40Warning: django.utils.translation.ugettext() is deprecated in favor of django.utils.translation.gettext().
    "attribute_validation_error": _(

../../usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oscarapi/serializers/fields.py:112
  /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oscarapi/serializers/fields.py:112: RemovedInDjango40Warning: django.utils.translation.ugettext() is deprecated in favor of django.utils.translation.gettext().
    "attribute_required": _("Attribute {code} is required."),

../../usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oscarapi/serializers/fields.py:113
  /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oscarapi/serializers/fields.py:113: RemovedInDjango40Warning: django.utils.translation.ugettext() is deprecated in favor of django.utils.translation.gettext().
    "attribute_missing": _(

../../usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oscarapi/serializers/fields.py:117
  /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oscarapi/serializers/fields.py:117: RemovedInDjango40Warning: django.utils.translation.ugettext() is deprecated in favor of django.utils.translation.gettext().
    "child_without_parent": _(

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR store/apps/api_extensions/tests/checkout/test_checkout_2.py - oscar.cor...
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========================= 9 warnings, 1 error in 0.27s =========================
```

Comment: Really hard to help without seeing your code and the full stack trace.

Comment: I append the stacktrace @solarissmoke, I think, I don't have more information.